# How to create a properties file in windows

Tags: windows

**How to create a properties file in windows**
I tried to search in google but could not find it. Thought it would help others.
Just use the powershell command to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

Run windows powershell prompt as administrator - command is "New-Item example-config.properties -type file"

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\myFolder>type nul >fileName.extension
```

Courtesy:https://www.wikihow.com/Create-and-Delete-Files-and-Directories-from-Windows-Command-Prompt